# "Преждевременное" прорисовывание анимации

Tags: ios, swift, анимация

Создаю анимацию рисования круга. В приложении есть кнопка, которая останавливает и запускает анимацию при повторном нажатии на неё. Анимация работает нормально, но когда я нажимаю паузу или вызываю `mediaPicker`, то анимация прорисовывается мгновенно. Почему такое происходит?

Анимация:

```
 func draw (duractionSong: Double){

    let progressLine = CAShapeLayer()
    let animateStrokeEnd = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    print(duractionSong)
    // set up some values to use in the curve
    let ovalStartAngle = CGFloat(90.01 * M_PI/180)
    let ovalEndAngle = CGFloat(180 * M_PI/180)
    let ovalRect = CGRectMake(97.5, 58.5, 125, 125)

    // create the bezier path
    let ovalPath = UIBezierPath()

    ovalPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(ovalRect), CGRectGetMidY(ovalRect)), radius: CGRectGetWidth(ovalRect) / 2, startAngle: ovalStartAngle, endAngle: ovalEndAngle, clockwise: true)

    // create an object that represents how the curve
    // should be presented on the screen
    progressLine.path = ovalPath.CGPath
    progressLine.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    progressLine.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    progressLine.lineWidth = 5
    progressLine.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    // add the curve to the screen
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(progressLine)

    print("process")
    // create a basic animation that animates the value 'strokeEnd'
    // from 0.0 to 1.0 over 3.0 seconds
    animateStrokeEnd.duration = duractionSong
    animateStrokeEnd.fromValue = 0.0
    animateStrokeEnd.toValue = 1.0


    // add the animation
    progressLine.addAnimation(animateStrokeEnd, forKey: "animate stroke end animation")





}
```

Пауза:

```
self.view.layer.speed = 0.0;

self.view.layer.timeOffset = self.view.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
```

Comment: можно весь код в паузе посмотреть? То, что есть в вопросе должно работать нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вы не тот лэйер пытаетесь остановить.
Вместо `self.view.layer` попробуйте создать референс на `progressLine` и работать с ним в паузе. Что-то типа:

```
self.progressLine.speed = 0.0;
self.progressLine.timeOffset = self.view.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
```

Comment: Да, это действительно была моя ошибка, спасибо.